# Ciclo for só é executado uma vez dentro de um while e devia ser sempre executado

Tags: java, android, for, while

```
listaA = new ArrayList <>();
                boolean n = true;
                while (listaA.size() < listab.size()) {
                    Log.i( "while ordena" , String.valueOf( listaA.size() ));
                    valorAl = nRandom.nextInt( listab.size() );
                    Log.i( "while ordena" , "   valor random  " + String.valueOf( valorAl ));
                    if (valorAl == listab.size()) {
                        valorAl = valorAl - 1;
                        Log.i( "while ordena" , "   valor random igual a listab.size");
                    }
                    if (n) {
                        listaA.add( listab.get( valorAl ) );
                        Log.i( "while ordena" ,"  1 valor na lista A");
                        n = false;
                    } else {
                        Log.i( "while ordena" , "  proximo valor da lista A - " + String.valueOf( listab.get( valorAl ).id ) );

                        Boolean igual =false;
//int y =0;
                        for (int y =0; y==(listaA.size()-1); y++){
                        if (listaA.get(y).id== listab.get( valorAl ).id )  {igual=true; Log.i( "while ordena" , "  já existe");}
                           if(!igual) {listaA.add( listab.get( valorAl ) );
                             Log.i( "while ordena" , "  adiciona novo");}
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Estou a usar este código para ordenar de forma aleatória a listaA com os elementos da listab.
Acontece é que só passa pelo for quando é adicionado o 2 elemento À listaA e depois não volta a entrar no for.
Eu estou mais habituado a usar o vb e lá o código funciona normalmente, mas no android studio fica num loop infinito, pois nunca mais é adicionado nenhum elemento À listaA.
Não sei se me faltou alguma coisa, para que o for seja executado correctamente, visto não estar muito habituado À linguagem java.

edit:
Eu coloquei o int y=0 fora do for para ver se seria o y que mantinha o valor após a primeira execução do for, mas tem o mesmo efeito, só entra no for 1 vez.
Por isso não estou a perceber porque o for não volta a ser executado.

Comment: Quantos valores tem na `listab`?

Answer (score 0):

A listab depende do numero de registos do firebase, ou seja, não se sabe.
A listaA o valor vai sendo incrementado À medida que vai sendo adicionado um novo elemento escolhido aleatoriamente da listab, ou seja, sempre que o valor novo não exista na listaA, é adicionado à listaA.
Começa com 0 elementos e é adicionado o 1º elemento no `if (n)`, na 2ª e restantes voltas do while é no for que é verificado se o numero aleatório já existe na listaA, se existir volta para o while para ser criado um novo numero aleatório, se não existir é adicionado à listaA.

No entanto já descobri qual era o problema, foi um erro de matemática da minha parte.
Eu usei o seguinte  `for (int y =0; y==(listaA.size()-1); y++)` e ao alterar para `for (int y =0; y<listaA.size(); y++)` já funciona correctamente.